# How to access parameters of THREE.TorusKnotGeometry using dat.GUI within aframe

Tags: aframe

I am using datGUI to adjust the internal params of a torus knot (p and q, which change its topology). The usual process is to get a reference to the THREE.geometry beneath the Aframe component using getObject3D, and passing this object and its properties (to be tweaked) into dat.GUI.

The problem is I can't find the path within the THREE. TorusKnotGeometry object to the properties ( p and q ) that I want to manipulate.

I (successfully) got a reference to the THREE.group that contains the TorusKnotGeometry using `el.getObject3D('mesh')`, and logged it to the console, and browsed through the object looking for the parameters that I wish to manipulate (p and q). The only place I could find them were within torusKnotg3D.geometry.metadata.parameters.

I passed this into dat.GUI, and it did not throw errors, but did not change the torus knot. So the question is, where are the parameters that will control the THREE.TorusKnotGeometry?

```
let torusKnot = document.querySelector("#torusKnot");
let torusKnot3D = document.querySelector("#torusKnot").object3D;
let torusKnotg3D = document.querySelector("#torusKnot").getObject3D('mesh');
tk3Dp=torusKnotg3D.geometry.metadata.parameters;

let gui = new dat.GUI();
tnParams = gui.addFolder("Torus Knot");
tnParams.add(tk3Dp, "p", 0, 12).name('p');
```

I expected that using `getObject3D()` would return the THREE. TorusKnotGeometry with the parameters I want to manipulate exposed, but I cannot find them.
With simpler objects, such as primitives inside a gltf-model, this is straightforward, but here the properties of the geometry component are not easily found.

Here is a glitch file
https://glitch.com/~ambient-light-gui

Here is the same file on my server, so you can browse the objects returned from getObject3D, logged to the console.

http://www.sensorium.love/experiments/yamashiro/bonsai/ambientLightGUI.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's not a matter of access, but how dat.gui works. 
It changes the parameters, but it doesn't update the geometry.

From a quick glance at [this](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/TorusKnotGeometry) example:

**1. The changes have to be registered**

The dat.gui folder has a `onChanged` defined:

```
folder.add( data, 'radius', 1, 20 ).onChange( generateGeometry );
```

**2. The geometry needs to be recreated**

1. `generateGeometry` is a function which creates a whole new Buffer geometry using the changed attributes, like this:

   ```
   let newGeo = new THREE.TorusKnotBufferGeometry(tk3Dp.radius, tk3Dp.tube,
                tk3Dp.tubularSegments, tk3Dp.radialSegments, tk3Dp.p, tk3Dp.q)
   ```

   Then it calls `updateGroupGeometry` providing the mesh, and the new geometry.
2. `updateGroupGeometry` disposes the old geometry and substitues it with the new one, like this:

   ```
   // here the mesh has no children:
   mesh.geometry.dispose()
   mesh.geometry = newGeo
   ```

Check it out in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/4ofgq9ru/) fiddle.

---

Although I'm applying the changes by myself, in the THREE example there is a whole big mechanism for detecting geometries and stuff. It's not a part of three.js, or dat.gui.js, let me know if you find out if it's a separate library.

---

**0. The TorusKnotGeometry parameters**

Like you found them -

```
// Mesh
let mesh = el.getObject3D('mesh')

// TorusKnotGeometry parameters
let tkgp = mesh.geometry.metadata.parameters;
```

Comment: Now it all makes sense. The geometry has to be rebuilt. Brilliant. Thanks!